# Capitalize part of string in Spark

Tags: string, dataframe, apache-spark, substring, capitalization

In Spark, I am looking for a way to capitalize just a part of a string (e.g. "ab" or "de") if it's found inside string.

Input dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("abcde",), ("aaabbb",)], ["c1"])
df.show()
# +------+
# |    c1|
# +------+
# | abcde|
# |aaabbb|
# +------+
```

Preferably using native Spark, I'd like to create a column containing capitalizations:

```
+------+------+
|    c1|    c2|
+------+------+
| abcde| ABcDE|
|aaabbb|aaABbb|
+------+------+
```

I thought about regex, but sadly, Spark (Java) regex does not support substitution with capitalization.
E.g. PCRE could use the `ab|de` and `\U\0\E` patterns [to get the desired result](https://regex101.com/r/UClFHN/1).

Comment: You can use multiple replacement expressions: `df.withColumn("c2", reduce(lambda a, b: F.regexp_replace(a, b, b.upper()), ["ab", "de"], F.col("c1")))`

Comment: Thank you! It's a valid option using PySpark.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I was only able to do it in PySpark, using `pandas_udf`. It's efficient using PySpark, however, it's not transferable to Scala.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
import re

@F.pandas_udf("string")
def to_upper(col: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    def repl(s):
        return re.sub(fr"(.*?)(ab|de|$)", lambda m: m.groups()[0] + m.groups()[1].upper(), s)
    return col.apply(repl)

df = df.withColumn("c2", to_upper("c1"))

df.show()
# +------+------+
# |    c1|    c2|
# +------+------+
# | abcde| ABcDE|
# |aaabbb|aaABbb|
# +------+------+
```